# PHP SQL query not searching the database properly

Tags: php, sql

I have this SQL query, which is executed from PHP:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM product 
WHERE ProductID LIKE '%$key%' 
OR ProductName LIKE '%$key%' 
OR ProductDescription LIKE '%$key%' 
OR ProductCategory LIKE '%$key%' LIMIT 1";
```

I can search for some things that show up fine however other things to do not even show up and I cannot see why. The search feature as a whole works fine but is just very glitchy? I've been told to index my database but im not sure where to start.

Comment: What `things` do you search fine and what not?

Comment: How is anyone supposed to help you fix "some thing" show up fine "other things" do not show up?

Comment: Indexing just speeds searches, it doesn't change the results. And indexing won't help with `LIKE` queries like this.

Comment: which things show up, which don't? please be more specific.

Comment: Make sure you're escaping `$key`.

Comment: Maybe the Letter casing?

Comment: Your query is wide open to SQL-Injection (you should read about it). Your (query) inability to find "some things" may be a side effect of that...

Comment: @GermannArlington thanks for the heads up! luckily this is for a uni project and we arent considering security exploits for it

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example search query I use when trying to find either a class or teacher name in a database. Notice the brackets ().

```
$resultGet = mysql_query(" SELECT * from $table where (className LIKE '%$searchQuery%' or teacherName='%$searchQuery%') AND recordStatus = '1' order by className asc ");
```

Comment: Same comments as to OP.
  
P.S. You need the brackets because your are using `AND recordStatus = '1'` with a group of `OR` selectors. OP's query does not need them (the brackets)